# Not saving model and script files in Hyperledger Composer tutorial

Tags: hyperledger-composer

Just starting with the basic Composer tutorial.  I paste in the updated model and script files into the empty-business-network but they don't seem to persist.  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Do you use the [composer-playground.mybluemix.net](http://composer-playground.mybluemix.net) or a local instance of the playground?

Comment: The mybluemix.net web instance.

Comment: ok, tell us more what do you want to do? Are there any errors? What browser do you use? Can you download the .bna?

Comment: I'm wanting to implement some simple model prototypes in the tool, export them to a .bna for later demos. There are no apparent error messages, the model or script code I paste in does not persist. I'm using Chrome Version 63.0.3239.84 64 bit. I was able to execute the other sample networks and download their .bna, just not able to create one from scratch.

Comment: I found the issue. The namespace in the tutorial examples is org.acme.mynetwork, the default model file namespace in the empty-business-network is org.acme.model.  Updating all references to org.acme.model fixed the issue with the file contents not being persisted.